# Creating a zero vector,and modifying it in theano

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I need to create a some fixed length(length equal to size of some other tensor vector which is passed) zero vector in theano.

```
def some_fun(self, y)
    x_h = T.fvector('x_h')
    ret = T.alloc(0, x_h)
    vec_h = theano.function(inputs=[x_h], outputs=ret)
    vec=vec_h(y.shape[0])
    vec[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]=1
```

When I am running this I am getting error "Shape arguments to Alloc must be integers, but argument 0 is not for apply node: x_h"

It may very big mistake, as I am new to theano.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [theano.tensor.zeros_like](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.zeros_like)? It seems like that should be a shortcut to what you're trying to do.

Then, when you get

> "TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object does not support item assignment"

you can replace the line `vec[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]=1` by using [theano.tensor.set_subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor) instead.

Comment: Yeah, that will work but the assignment vec[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]=1 is showing error.

Comment: Sorry , I should have mentioned earlier, "TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Edited the answer above to reflect this.